# letsencrypt ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Tags: spring-boot, lets-encrypt

I generated letsencrypt certificate for my site.

I installed a certificate with this command for my subdomain pointed to a different machine

sudo ./certbot-auto certonly --standalone --email email@myemail.com --agree-tos --rsa-key-size 4096 -d www.ns-dev01.qubyk.com

Below are properties in spring boot properties.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: test-sever

server:
  port: 443
  ssl:
    key-store: /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.ns-dev01.qubyk.com/keystore.p12
    key-store-password: testpassword
    enabled: true
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-alias: tomcat

security:
  require-ssl: true
```

Accessing the site in chrome returns

> www.ns-dev01.qubyk.com uses an unsupported protocol.
>   ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

In safari it works with no errors. What is it Im missing here?

Comment: According to SSLLabs [your server only allows DHE-RSA keyexchange](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.ns-dev01.qubyk.com) and [Chrome no longer supports (any) DHE keyexchange](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=619194). Observe in the list of client simulations Chrome fails. PS: using an auth-only cert with key stronger than the CA (LE is 2048) is a complete waste of time and CPU.

Comment: I tried to add cipher as below but this throws ex None of the [ciphers] specified are supported by the SSL engine

server.ssl.ciphers=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

Comment: What version and type of Java (Oracle/Sun, IBM, a distro, other) are you running on, and have any changes been made in its security configuration?

Comment: Im using spring boot 1.8 and my machine has Java 9-internal. I added these SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA cyphers it tends to work but it disabled seems to be disabled DHE

Comment: (1) Oracle j9 does not say 'internal' and does support ECDHE (and other EC), and I'm pretty sure but can't easily check OpenJDK also, so I don't know what you have (2) don't use (any suite including) RC4; it's been seriously weakened by attacks over the past decade or so and officially prohibited since 2015 by RFC7465 (3) yes, if you configure only non-DHE suites, it disables DHE; if you want both DHE (for other clients) and non-DHE (for Chrome) suites configure both of them. To make Chrome somewhat happier, configure at least some (nonDHE) AES+GCM suites (it prefers AEAD over CBC)